# Origin of the "세-탁!" Call that echoes around apartment buildings

Tags: advertising

I've lived / stayed in a few apartment buildings around Seoul, and in each of them you can regularly hear an eerie slow, monotone call of "세-탁!" echoing up and down the stairs - I understand this is a pick-up and drop-off dry cleaning service.

I am wondering if there is any knowledge of how the distinctive "세-탁!" call originated?

Comment: thats something like traditional things. like the orgin of hello.

Comment: @김성훈 'hello' does have some information as to its origin -  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello - so I'm wondering if there's any similar info about this call!

Comment: See https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EC%84%B8%ED%83%81

Comment: @C.Wang it's the distinctive, musical delivery I was interested in, rather than the word itself. It's a shame I don't have a recording!

Comment: If they just ring doorbells without any comments, people have to go back to get their money to pay for laundry service. I guess they try to notice people that they are cleaners, so they can open the door and pay immediately.

Answer (score 3):

Nobody here has interest origin of 세~탁 call here. You have a curiosity!
Why 세~탁 call is accepted as a culture is because it exists for long time, and similar calls are abundant.
Laundry service shouts "세-탁-", Some food service shouts "찹쌀떡-", and "메밀묵-". At summer fruit seller shouts "수-박-", the list goes on.

They want people to know about their service, but they think it's kind of rude to go directly to customers. So they choose indirect way to make their presence know to people. Low and slow service calls.

Comment: 찹쌀떡- is definitely a distinctive call too - at least I often heard sellers singing it to the same (or similar) tunes!